# How to set and lock the JScrollpane to the bottom?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

How can I set the JScrollPane to the bottom of the JTextArea? I tried the 
`DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);` But it didnt work it didnt automatically go down.

Here is my current code

```
public class subTextAreaMessages extends JTextArea implements ActionListener{
private ArrayList al;
public subTextAreaMessages()
{
    setEditable(false);
    listTheMessages();
    Timer t = new Timer(500,this);
    t.start();
}

public void listTheMessages()
{
    ConnectMysql.getUsernamesTest(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try {
        System.out.print(getText(185,186));
    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 }




jspTextField = new JScrollPane(new subTextAreaMessages());

mainPanel2.add(jspTextField ,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: I always find it easier to extend JPanel and add stuff to it. Much easier control over the layoutmanager of the JPanel class. Then you simply add the panel to whatever, it is just another JComponent.

Comment: What does this code have to do with your problem? I don't see where you append any text to the text area.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact requirement, one of the following should help

1. [Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/)
2. [Smart Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/smart-scrolling/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that my text was being completely replaced periodically by similar content and users wanted to keep the visible location within the large text content fixed.
My solution was to implement my own BoundedRangeModel by extending the DefaultBoundedRangeModel.  Then I told the ScrollPane's ScrollBars to use an instance of my model and all went well.